# How to fix Drupal update: 7082 - Add 'jquery-extend-3.4.0.js' to the 'jquery' library

Tags: php, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I want to make an core update from Drupal 7.62 to Drupal 7.67 (you can find the releases [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/releases?api_version%5B%5D=103)).

I have followed the steps in in [this manual](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/update/core-option-3).

In step 11 i ran the http://hostname/update.php and getting this message:

```
7082 - Add 'jquery-extend-3.4.0.js' to the 'jquery' library.
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]
AUSSTEHENDE AKTUALISIERUNGEN translated: Pending updates

When I press 'Apply pending updates' then drupal refers me to the main page. When I refer to /reports/status than I can see that the update has not run:

[image]
Translation: Database update. Some modules need to update their database schema. The script for updating the database should be executed immediately.

When I press 'script for updating the database' I come back to update.php every time, but nothing will be updated.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try to run update with drush debug mod ? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.install/function/system_update_7082/7.x Can you trad error message in english please ?

Comment: @Fky: I have followed the steps in in this official manual: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/update/core-option-3

Comment: Can you translate that message in Eng pls ?

Comment: Also you could check the server logs to see if there's something..?

Comment: No, there are no logs on the server.

Comment: try this https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/upgrading-drupal/2011-08-30/database-update-runs-with-no-errors-but-status-report#comment-9059569